# Are HTML user agents required to submit form data in a particular order?

Tags: html, forms, web-standards

For a given HTML form, is a user agent required to build the submit request in a particular order?

I was looking through the HTML 4.0.1 Specification and it doesn't seem to specify the order that "successful controls" become part of the request on submission. [Section 17.13.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3), Processing form data, states:

> When the user submits a form (e.g., by activating a submit button), the user agent processes it as follows.
>
> **Step one: Identify the [successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)**
>
> **Step two: Build a form data set**
>
> A *form data set* is a sequence of [control-name](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#control-name)/[current-value](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#current-value) pairs constructed from successful controls
>
> **Step three: Encode the form data set**
>
> The form data set is then encoded according to the content type specified by the `enctype` attribute of the `FORM` element.
>
> **Step four: Submit the encoded form data set**

At step two, the form data set is described as a *sequence*, so the order in which it is encoded in Step 3 is presumably fixed. But, this begs the question of what the order of successful controls is in the form data set.

For example, given the following HTML form:

```
<form action="#" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="key1" value="value1" />
<div>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="key2" value="value2" />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="key3" value="value3" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="key5" value="value5" />
</form>
```

Could the form data set be

> [ (`"key1"`, `"value1"`), (`"key2"`, `"value2"`), (`"key3"`, `"value3"`), (`"submit"`, `"Submit"`), (`"key5"`, `"value5"`) ]

(I.e. a depth-first search of the DOM);  or

> [ (`"key1"`, `"value1"`), (`"key5"`, `"value5"`), (`"key3"`, `"value3"`), (`"submit"`, `"Submit"`), (`"key2"`, `"value2"`) ]

(A breadth-first search);  or even a nondeterministic order resulting from iterating the control-name/current-value pairs in a randomized hashtable?

Testing this form with IE 9 and Firefox 9.0.1, it seems that both use the depth-first search order. Perhaps other browsers are different. The question is whether this order is prescribed somewhere.

Comment: Don't think there is an order they are required to follow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you continue to section [17.13.4 of the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4), it states that the default content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  The section for that content type says:

> The control names/values are listed **in the order they appear in the document**.

This would suggest a depth-first traversal and would seem to agree with your browser tests.